# Cohomology of coherent sheaves on Deligne Mumford stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, algebraic-stacks

Suppose that $\cal X$ is tame Deligne Mumford stack with generic trivial inertia. Let $X$ be its muduli space and $f:{\cal X}\to X$ the projection.

Let $\cal F$ be a coherent sheaf on $\cal X$.

Is it true that
$$H^i({\cal X; F})=H^i(X;f_\ast({\cal F}))?$$
More in general, is it true that $R^if_\ast({\cal F})=0$  for $i>0$ and we can deduce the displayed formula from an analogous of the Leray Spectral sequence?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Yes, that is true for tame Deligne-Mumford stacks (it fails for non-tame Deligne-Mumford stacks).

Comment: A tame DM stack $\mathcal{X}$ is such that the coarse moduli space map $\mathcal{X} \to X$ is also a good moduli space, and hence your question follows (in fact its also true for $\mathcal{F}$ quasi-coherent and not just coherent).

Comment: I wrote this as an MO answer some time ago (probably about the cohomological dimension of a DM stack).  By flat base change, you can compute the stalks of the higher direct image sheaves $R^if_*(\mathcal{F})$ after a flat base change of $X$.  By a result of Abramovich-Vistoli (that was probably a folk result until they wrote it down), there is a flat cover such that, Zariski locally on the domain $\mathcal{X}$ equals $[Y/G]$ for a tame group $G$ and an affine morphism $Y\to X$.  Now use the usual spectral sequence, $H^q(G;H^p(Y,\mathcal{F}_Y))\Rightarrow H^{p+q}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{F})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I always considered the map to moduli space as "finite map ramified of degree one" . So you confirm that this intuition is correct?

Comment: If that helps you, then you should use it.  It might be worth bearing in mind an example like the action of $\mu_n$ on $\text{Spec}\ k[\epsilon]/\langle \epsilon^{n-1} \rangle$ in the evident way.  The stack quotient is nonreduced, but the coarse moduli space is just $\text{Spec}\ k$.